# How to backup a SVN repository with only SVN access?

Tags: svn, backup

I've got some code hosted at a svn server; I'm pretty sure they do a good job of making backups, but I'd like to make my own - just in case. I only have "svn access" to this machine; how can I make backups?

I could make something simple which just checks out every day and backups that, but I'd like something which captures each revision as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cloning your repo into another repo? Eg. git repo?

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn